# glfx.js blur on canvas - getting undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to apply the Lens Blur effect to a canvas using glfx.js Javascript library, but getting an error `undefined is not a function`.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("test_1");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function () {
    fitImageOn(canvas, imageObj); // draws the image onto the canvas, this works without any issues
    canvas.lensBlur(10, 0.75, 0).update(); // <---- error reported for this line

};

imageObj.src = "/images/test_1_image.png";
```

I also tried `canvas.lensBlur(10, 0.75, 0)` function but I get the same error.  The HTML has a simple canvas object with height and width attributes set.

```
<canvas id="test_1" height="350" width="350" ></canvas>
```

Here's a [demo page](http://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/demo/#lensBlur) that shows the effect in action on the official website. Thanks

Comment: Use like canvas.lensBlur(10, 0.75, 0); after that canvas.update(); seperately

Comment: @AntoKing, hi. I get the same error. The error comes even with the first line only without the update. The link to the javascipt function is there and loaded, so it's not a reference error either.